# How to implement a new page in Android and return results( Able to hit back button)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

Currently the method Im using right now(Which I feel is really sloppy) is calling this on a function called when the button is clicked through xml

```
setContentView(R.layout.selectcontacts);
```

Which for some reason bugs the navigation bar to white rather than what is what one the previous page(blue)

XML layout for select contacts:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/view2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/thetoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield"
android:dividerHeight="2dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:id="@+id/contactlistview"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2">

</ListView>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fabupload"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_upload_done"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="registerDoneClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a new activity, and return result(s) from the activity, you want to use the method startActivityForResult

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Here's the explaination of this method from the Android documentation:

"Sometimes you want to get a result back from an activity when it ends. For example, you may start an activity that lets the user pick a person in a list of contacts; when it ends, it returns the person that was selected. To do this, you call the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) version with a second integer parameter identifying the call. The result will come back through your onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) method.

When an activity exits, it can call setResult(int) to return data back to its parent. It must always supply a result code, which can be the standard results RESULT_CANCELED, RESULT_OK, or any custom values starting at RESULT_FIRST_USER. In addition, it can optionally return back an Intent containing any additional data it wants. All of this information appears back on the parent's Activity.onActivityResult(), along with the integer identifier it originally supplied."